# Machine learning techniques for small datasets

Tags: finance-mathematics, machine-learning, quants

I am dealing with financial data which is available on a Monthly basis. I am planning to apply machine learning techniques like LSTM but issue here is that overall I have very limited training dataset as even if I take 10 years of data, I have only 120 data points. It may lead to overfitting, could you please suggest alternative method to deal with this issue?

Comment: What is more important for you: obtain a decent model or use machine learning? And how restrictive is your definition of machine learning? Since the dataset is small, I would go for a simple model (thus perhaps no machine learning, appropriately defined), perhaps from a Bayesian angle so that some prior information could be exploited to limit the variance of the estimators.

Comment: how many features per month do you have?

Comment: @shadi I have two features a month

Comment: Better just do a scatter chart with each feature on an axis and use color for the target. Visually try to make out a relationship first. It might as well be linear after some transformation like log